# Copying  database in assets to Android's internal databases fails at first attempt in the emulator

Tags: android, database, android-emulator, assets

I have a database (1.69 MB) in assets to need copy to internal databases folder. My problem is that for the first try db is copied but not with exact tables. It becomes 3072 (3kB) size in the emulator file explorer.

When I look in that db with sqlite explorer I can't see my tables. The only table exists in db is android_metadata table with one column of my locale info.

But if I clear that db from databases and re-run the application, it seems working for this time. Why does it fail for the first try?  How can I be sure it won't happen in real devices? 
Is that a bug with the emulator?

Comment: If you execute PRAGMA user_version; query on your database in assets what is the value you are gettin? If this is a invalid value SqliteOpenHelper class will be calling a onCreate which will delete anything existing and create a new one. when are you creating SqliteOpenhelper before or after copying?

Comment: thanks for quick replay, PRAGMA user_version gives me 0. i have never heard of it. What to do with this zero?

In my application, i am creating SqliteOpenHelper just after copying the database.

So if it is the case, what should i do?
Why at next attempts it doesn't delete my tables?

By the way, my sqliteopenhelper onCreate, onUpgrade methods are empty.

Comment: Add some logs and see if for some reason that method is getting called the first time you are copying database.If that is the case..may be you can just put your copying code there. Also are you sure you copy succeeded?

Comment: strangely i realized that my copying code started not working. I just write:

    String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/" + DbAdapter.DATABASE_NAME; 
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
but it gives me the following errors, beginning throwing file not found exception. What kind of details am i missing because it was working before?

     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.databasetrial.it/databases/mydata.db

**note**:i update my db with PRAGMA user_version = 1

Comment: I believe databases folder may not be created by the time you are trying to copy the file. since it doesn't have access to create directory it might be failing. see if you can create databases directory first and then try copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally i've come up the conclusion with the help of Naresh (thank you). Here the short summary:
at the first run i was trying to copy my 1.6mb data.db file from assets to /data.../databases folder which one never existed. So

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
```

line gave error. But after that line my dbhelper instance called getreadabledatabase which created the databases folder under specified path. Android put a db with same name but no useful data in it. In my copyDatabase method i updated it as follows:

```
InputStream is = getBaseContext().getAssets().open(assetsDB);

            //when there is no databases folder fileoutputstream gives error,
            //we have to make sure databases folder exists
            DbAdapter temp = new DbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            temp.open();        //gets readable database: creates databases folder containing DB_NAME db
            temp.close();       //since we don use this temp, we close

            //this wont give error: because path is now exists (databases folder exists)
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destPath);

            //copying 1K bytes at a time
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
```

this is the solution i've come up with. By the way, former sdk's of 2.3 assets database size should be less than 1mb. This is anohter issue and found the solution [here](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/)